# Alternative to Shutter in Windows

Tags: images

I absolutely love Shutter for Linux. It is extremely [feature rich](http://shutter-project.org/about/). I particularly like to be able to quickly capture areas of the screen and have it be automatically saved. Uploading to imgur is a breeze and is really useful in my line of work.

The Snipping Tool in Windows is very lackluster. It requires you to manually save every screenshot, and there are virtual zero extra features.

The basic features I would like:

- Quickly capture regions and save them in one step (rather than capture and go through the saving process like Snipping Tool)
- Upload images to imgur within the application
- Edit images so I can highlight pertinent parts, draw arrows etc.

Are there any alternatives to Shutter that work in Windows that come close?

Comment: Could you please list all of the features you like about Shutter?

Comment: Or better, those features you like to see in the tools recommended here :)

Comment: @Cornelius didn't spot that one when searching. Thanks! I'll refer to that and flagged this one as dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At work (where I'm forced to use Windows), I'm using **[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)** for this. It's even available as portable app, so you can install it without administrative powers.

Greenshot can do a lot of things, like

- capture region (even "capture ***last*** region", for repeated actions)
- capture window (naturally)
- capture full screen
- capture Internet Exploder
- Integration for Picasa, Imgur, Photobucket, Imgur, Flickr, Dropbox, Box
- integrated image editor

[image: Greenshot Editor]
<sup>Greenshot Image Editor (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenshot); click image for larger variant)</sup>

I'm using *Greenshot* for years already, and really like it. Though I never used its "cloud features": if they work only half as good as everything else, they should be great as well :) Just give it a try, it's free and open source – so nothing to lose. When in doubt, try the [portable version](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Portable-Greenshot-Download-160652.html) first.

For more details, please see [Greenshots Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenshot).

Comment: I would even say Greenshot is faster than Shutter, considering the immediate context menu to copy to clipboard or upload. Great tool

Comment: I didn't make any performance tests (which would require at least comparable hardware ;) – but I didn't feel any differences in speed here (on Linux, I use Shutter, too ;)

Comment: Great tool! Works fantastic for context menu shots too!

Answer (score 1):

I use [**PicPick**](http://picpick.org).

- free for personal use
- supports uploading to Facebook, Skype, Twitter and via FTP to any host
- has some nice tools (ruler, protractor)
- screenshots of window, region, controls etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think [Ashampoo Snap 7](https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pin/1024/multimedia-software/Ashampoo-Snap-7) is the best (although I only have version 6):

If I compare the features to the website you gave in your question:

- Capture a Specific Area: **yes**
- Capture your Desktop: **yes**
- Capture a Window: **yes**
- Capture a Menu or Tooltip: **yes**
- Add Text, Arrows, Rectangles, Ellipse: **yes** (*as a bonus*, you can add numbered steps, zoom in to buttons - useful for writing tutorials for websites etc.)
- Censor / Pixelize to Hide Private Data: **yes** (you can blur / erase)
- Crop: **yes**
- Share easily: **yes**
- Join the Cloud: **yes** (Ashampoo Webspace - I've never used this though)

Bonuses:

- Replaces the system 'print screen'
- Gives you the option of having the program in taskbar / 'capture bar' anywhere on your screen
- Very good editing features
- Includes a 'colour picker' so you can see what colour something is when you like it (useful for designing etc.)

To save, just press your normal 'print screen' button, press enter.

To edit, just press your normal 'print screen' button, start editing.

It's paid, but very cheap. Honestly, you could wait a few weeks and you will find this program as a giveaway on [GiveawayOfTheDay](http://giveawayoftheday.com/) or [Glarysoft Giveaway](http://giveaway.glarysoft.com/) (Ashampoo are very actively giving away programs for free). In fact, [this giveaway](http://www.ashampoo.com/lpa/softpedia-easter) from Easter is still going on (via Ashampoo's website). And [this one](http://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/lpa/gift) (via Ashampoo's website)!

Here's a screenshot, take a look at the top, right and left - those are all, expandable, editing and sharing tools!

[image]